# How to replay observable?

Tags: rx-java

I have this code:

```
Observable<Contact> phoneContactsObservable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe....
ReplaySubject subject = ReplaySubject.create();
phoneContactsObservable.subscribe(subject)
Observable.combineLatest(subject,(PublishSubject<List>) getContacts(), new Func2<....).subscribe()
Observable.combineLatest(subject,(PublishSubject<List>)getFBContacts(), new Func2<....).subscribe()
```

If I have an error in `getContacts` then `Func2` in `getFBContacts` doesn't run, and then I do some methods and want to rerun this all `Observables`.

How can I do this?

Comment: I suggest you to improve your example by reading the [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make the code easier to read. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have hooks to the observable (`doOn...`) - like `doOnError`, `doOnTerminate` or even `doOnSubscribe` (which I'd use to try and never cause an error).

That said, there is an example in the [docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html) for a simple retry-with-delay pattern. Note that it does not retry on the same element, but on the next element by re-subscribing to the observable:

```
Observable.create((Subscriber<? super String> s) -> {
      System.out.println("subscribing");
      s.onError(new RuntimeException("always fails"));
  }).retryWhen(attempts -> {
      return attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), (n, i) -> i).flatMap(i -> {
          System.out.println("delay retry by " + i + " second(s)");
          return Observable.timer(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      });
  }).toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Will give:

```
subscribing
delay retry by 1 second(s)
subscribing
delay retry by 2 second(s)
subscribing
delay retry by 3 second(s)
subscribing
```